# Gain of a steady state Kálmán filter

Tags: st.statistics, signal-analysis, stochastic-filtering

It is well known that the state covariance of a steady-state Kálmán filter is the solution of a discrete Riccati equation.

$$P_\infty = F(P_\infty - P_\infty H^T(HP_\infty H^T+R)^{-1}HP_\infty)F^T + Q$$

From there, one can compute the gain of the filter:

$$K_\infty = P_\infty H^T(R+HP_\infty H^T)^{-1}$$
Is it the case that the gain is itself the solution of a Riccati equation?

Comment: This is outside my area, but any chance you'd get a better answer on Cross Validated?